# Trying to add native Google-Map in ionic2 App but I am getting "Runtime Error Cannot find module "ionic-native"

Tags: javascript, google-maps, ionic2, angular2-routing, hybrid-mobile-app

> Runtime Error Cannot find module "ionic-native" Error: Error: Cannot
>   find module "ionic-native" at Object.
>   (http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:55809:7)at__webpack_require__(http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:20:30)atObjecthttp://localhost:8100/build/mai.js:74803:72)at__webpack_require__(http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:20:30)atObjecthttp://localhost:8100/build/main.js:55744:81)at__webpack_require__(http://local

I tried all stack answers but didn't get the right solution.

package.json

```
{
   "name": "ionic-hello-world",
   "version": "0.0.0",
   "author": "Ionic Framework",
   "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
   "private": true,
   "scripts": {
      "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
      "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
      "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
      "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
      "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
    },
"dependencies": {
 "@angular/common": "4.1.0",
 "@angular/compiler": "4.1.0",
 "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.1.0",
 "@angular/core": "4.1.0",
 "@angular/forms": "4.1.0",
 "@angular/http": "4.1.0",
 "@angular/platform-browser": "4.1.0",
 "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.1.0",
 "@ionic-native/core": "^3.7.0",
 "@ionic-native/geolocation": "^3.10.2",
 "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "3.7.0",
 "@ionic-native/status-bar": "3.7.0",
 "@ionic/storage": "2.0.1",
 "ionic-angular": "3.2.1",
 "ionic-native": "^3.5.0",
 "ionicons": "3.0.0",
 "rxjs": "5.1.1",
 "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
 "zone.js": "0.8.10"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@ionic/app-scripts": "1.3.7",
  "typescript": "2.2.1"
},
"cordovaPlugins": [
  "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
  "cordova-plugin-console",
  "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
  "cordova-plugin-device",
  "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
  "ionic-plugin-keyboard"
],
"cordovaPlatforms": [],
"description": "maps: An Ionic project"
}
```

Comment: are you trying in a device/emulator ? can you add package.json by [edit]ing the question?

Comment: trying in Ionic-Lab, but it's showing error. I also checked in real device but it's showing blank.